# Changing what I'm drawing with OpenGl when user touches screen

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm developing an Android application. I'm very new on it.

I have the following classes:

```
class CustomGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView

class CustomRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
```

`CustomGLSurfaceView` uses `CustomRenderer` to render a cube on `onDrawFrame` method.

I've added an `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` on `CustomGLSurfaceView` to manage touch events:

```
class CustomGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    // For touch inputs - previous touch (x, y)
    private float previousX;
    private float previousY;

    private CustomRenderer myRenderer;

    public CustomGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        myRenderer = new CustomRenderer();
        setRenderer(myRenderer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float currentX = event.getX();
          float currentY = event.getY();
          switch (event.getAction()) {
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                 myRenderer.handleMovement(currentY, currentY, previousX, previousY);
          }
          // Save current x, y
          previousX = currentX;
          previousY = currentY;
          return true;  // Event handled
    }
}
```

May I have to modify `onDrawFrame` to draw something new or to rotate the cube? I thing I must do it on `handleMovement`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the APIDemo project in the samples directory of the SDK. Specifically the TouchRotateActivity.java file for an example. Since you mentioned you are new to Android, I would recommend going through the APIDemo app to see what is possible/available with sample code.